# Map values from one list to values in another

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

I'm trying to run through a `for` loop, but looking at the indices, rather than the values of the list. My list looks like this:

```
ubermin_values = [8350.1416, 13167.329, 29200.063, 19283.514, 23596.0309...]
```

and it has a total of 100 values (but this changes with each run of the program).
I'm trying to keep track of which value in `minimum_pixels` each value in `ubermin_values` came from, for plotting. If I use this loop in my code,

```
ubermin_vals_x = []
for i in ubermin_values:
    value = ubermin_pixels[i]
    ubermin_vals_x.append(minimum_pixels[i])
```

it tries to iterate over the values (8350.1416, 13167.329...) but of course this can't be done. I think my scheme should work if I can iterate over the *indices* of `ubermin_values`, rather than the values, but I can't see how to do that.

If it helps, here's how the first values should be mapped:
[image]

so that I can plot the points (4, 8350.1416), (10, 13167.329), (7, 29200.063), etc.

The `numpy` docs list [nditer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#tracking-an-index-or-multi-index) for iterating over arrays. Am I on the right track with this, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you mention `numpy` when you are clearly using a `list`?

Comment: Ok @juanpa, thanks for those comments. I see that I can use `enumerate` to access the indices of the list, but I'm sorry that I can't see how to associate the values in the fourth list with the values in the first, as in my screenshot. How can I do that using a `for` loop?